# Do most tyres have the year of manufacture printed on them?

Tags: tires

I recently came back from a few weeks holiday to find a rim with an old tire on it had completely deflated. The tire was needing replacement anyway so I took it to a tire shop to get a new tire put on. When he saw the tire, the fitter said *"Wow. That's old."* and pointed to a code that said 05 on the sidewall. He stated that it was manufactured in 2005 and so (given that it's now 2016) was a very old tire.

Do most/all tyre manufacturers put these dates on the sidewall? It would be very informative when doing a car (or tire) purchase to be able to determine the age of the tires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do. There's a 4 digit code on the side of the tyres, the last 2 digits refer to the year. Here's a good video that explains where to find the year & a few other things about tyres (tyre code bit starts around 1.50): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoIFaPFMmv4